# Access Urban Airship Constant From PhoneGap

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova

Does anyone know how I can access the APID constant - EXTRA_APID (com.urbanairship.push.APID)
from within PhoneGap or in Javascript?

Thanks!

Comment: I wrote a Java plugin using this easy to follow tutorial - http://catchmayuri.blogspot.com/2011/05/getting-access-of-android-java-code-to.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to write a Java plugin for PhoneGap using this to get the APID:

```
PushPreferences prefs = PushManager.shared().getPreferences();
String apid =  prefs.getPushId();
```

Then access this variable from javascript as per the PhoneGap plugin docs.

Comment: please can you provide full example , how to access  urban airship constant from phonegap?

Comment: @Humayoo There's a link to the tutorial I used in the comments above.